# Jquery / Javascript - Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Google doesn`t execute my JS code. In Firefox everything works fine

```
$('a[href="#pricends"]').click(function(){
    $("div.text_1").text(($("div.text_1").text() == 'smth1') ? 'smth2' : 'smth1')
    $("div.text_2").text(($("div.text_2").text() == 'smth2') ? 'smth1' : 'smth2')

if ( $('div.text_1').text().contains("smth1") ) {
//smth here
}
```

Chrome console output points to "if" line above.

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function 
>   (anonymous function)
>   f.event.dispatch jquery-1.7.2.min.js:3
>   h.handle.i

How to fix this? Nothing goes at mind now, name function and compare it with bool before if ?

Comment: I'm just guessing here but wouldn't .text() just return a string and thus not be able to chain a .contains() method on it?

Comment: Strings in JavaScript don't have a `.contains()` method, though it's coming in ECMAScript 6 and currently available in Firefox. Chrome has it flagged as an experimental feature.

Comment: nice comment 'cookie monster', thanks. Thanks to everybody also, thats my 1st question and truely say, that I found answer before saw reply in diff StackO answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call .contains() on the text value returned from .text().

If you test the value after extracting it with jQuery you should be ok.

```
var divText = $('div.text_1').text();
if(divText.indexOf("smth1") != -1){
  //do your stuff...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this:

```
if ( $('div.text_1').text().indexOf("smth1") !== -1 ) {
  //smth here
}
```

The `indexOf` will return something other than -1 if "smth1" exists somewhere in your text.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan not sure I get what the IE8 comment is about?

Comment: indexOf doesn't exist in ie8

Comment: Ah, that's on an `Array` not a `String` -- which does work just fine.

Comment: To clarify... `.indexOf()` works in all versions of IE on `Strings` but in IE8 and below the `Array` object did not support an `.indexOf()` method.

Comment: @scunliffe +1 **my bad** must be the late hour... +1 this answer for being the first to answer.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan no worries, it is confusing too when the method name (and behavior) is essentially identical ;-)

Comment: @scunliffe I thought I've learned almost everything but sometimes yes... it just vanishes from memory :)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use the same check you used when choosing which text to append:

```
if ( $('div.text_1').text() === "smth1" ) {
  // do it
}
```

Comment: This is something I was about to add as answer. +1

Answer (score 0):

Also another way to do it with **a single class**

*[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/sumoh/1/edit)*

```
<a href="#pricends">CLICK</a>

<div class="smth">smth1</div>
<div class="smth">smth2</div>
```

jQ:

```
var $smth = $(".smth"); // Cache your elements

$('a[href="#pricends"]').click(function( e ){

  e.preventDefault(); // Prevent Browser default anchor behavior

  $smth.text(function(i, txt){
    return txt=='smth1'?'smth2':'smth1';
  });

});
```

Somewhat extended:

```
var $smth = $(".smth"); // Cache your elements

$('a[href="#pricends"]').click(function( e ){  
  e.preventDefault();
  $smth.text(function(i, txt){
    if(txt==="smth1"){
      // do something with $(this)
      // or do something else
    }
    // and afterwards thange text
    return txt=='smth1'?'smth2':'smth1';
  });
});
```